# While loop doesn't stop (Bash)

Tags: bash

I want to get delete all of the blank lines and lines with spaces (if any exist (ONLY from the bottom of the file)) and then to remove one more line (also ONLY from the bottom of the file).

I have this code:

```
while [[ "$last_line" =~ ^$ ]] || [[ "$last_line" =~ ^[[:space:]]+$ ]]
do
    sed -i -e '${/$/d}' "./file.txt"
done
    sed -i -e '${/$/d}' "./file.txt"
```

For some reason the loop doesn't stop and it deletes everything in the file. What is the matter?

Comment: You're not changing the value of `$last_line` within the loop, so how *could* it stop?

Comment: Wow, I have forgotten about that, thank you, works great!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tac` and `awk` combination for this:

```
tac file | awk 'BEGIN{p=0} p<=1 && /^[[:blank:]]*$/{p=1; next} p==1{p++; next} 1' | tac

tac file         # prints files in reverse
/^[[:blank:]]*$/ # will find all blank/empty lines using search pattern    
tac              # reverse the file content
```

Comment: I never heard of `tac` before (and it's not on OSX Terminal). So I logged into a linux box and looked up the man page... Basically it's `cat` in reverse. I guess that is pretty obvious in retrospect :D

Comment: Hmm I am also on OSX but I have installed all gnu utils using `home brew` hence `tac` is there for me.

Comment: I didn't know that was a package - top tip! I remember having some trouble with some of the BSD-flavoured utils in the past - missing flags etc. Thanks @anubhava